# eclipse plugin: check selected project is closed or open

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I created a plugin which queries the selected project Name & Path. Here is the code:

```
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
if (firstElement != null) {
    if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable) {
        IProject project = (IProject) ((IAdaptable) firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
        IPath path = project.getFullPath();
        IPath location = project.getLocation();
    }
}
```

But, how could i check if the selected project is closed or open ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IProject` has an `isOpen()` method. That will tell you if the project is currently open.

Comment: But is there any difference between project which was closed (but still present in Project Explorer view) and the project which is just physically located in the workspace? For both of them I'm getting isOpen() == false, but I would like to differentiate such types of "closed" projects.